# Is it possible to cache javascript data visualization result?

Tags: javascript, caching, browser, data-visualization

I have a dataset of 4000 points of data, I use vis.js to visualize it on the browser.
But it takes about 7mins to show the while plot.
Every time refreshing the webpage needs another 7mins to regenerate the plot again.

Is it possible to cache javascript data visualization result?

Comment: 7min for 4000 points? Something is wrong somewhere.

Comment: Hello @Kaiido, 4000 points might contains a lot of edges

Comment: We'll need to see more of what you're doing anyway.

Comment: You can try to cache the data in `localStorage`, but 7 minutes is really long anyway